# ActionBar Buttons : Unreachable statement

Tags: android, android-actionbar, switch-statement

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code ? (I bet it's something stupid but i can't find it..)

[image: Unreachable statement]

My code :

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_go_home:
            //go home action
            Intent i = new Intent(this, UserProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
            break;
        case R.id.action_select_categories:
            //select categories
            return true;
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            //refresh timeline

            return true;
        default :
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a **return** statement before your switch.

You should fix it like:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

switch (item.getItemId()){
....
```